# How do I trigger a Workflow Rule to send an Outbound Message when a new Feed Email has been added to a Case?

Tags: email, email2case, servicecloud, workflowoutboundmessage, workflowrule

I currently have several Workflow Rules listening to changes on Case objects. I have one for Feed Items, Case Comments, and any updates to the Case itself.

We recently turned on Email to Case so now we have updates to the Case coming in via an Email Feed Item.

So I updated our Workflow Rule to say

`Feed Item: Feed Item Type EQUALS Text Post,Advanced Text Post,Case Comment Feed,Email Message Feed`

That didn't work so I changed the EQUALS to be CONTAINS and I also tried INCLUDES, and none of those worked either.

Then I tried creating a WorkflowRule on the `EmailMessage` object. I think this would work, but I want our `WorkflowRule` to send an outbound message to our server. It doesn't look like you can do this with a WorkflowRule attached to EmailMessage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want workflow rule to be evaluated when first time email-to-case is created or you want everytime email comes to case then rule to be executed?

Comment: Ideally every time an email is sent or received on a case @SantanuBoral